# moving the image infinitely from left to right using tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI in which an image is moving from left to right. But it is moving just once from left to right.I want this image to move infinitely times from left to right.
The code for moving the image once is:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
#canvas1.create_image(50, 50, image=photo1)
def next_image(event=None):

    canvas1.move(item, 10, 0)
    canvas1.after(20, next_image)# <--- Use Canvas.move method.




image1 = r"C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pygame\examples\data\file.gif"
photo1 = PhotoImage(file=image1)
width1 = photo1.width()
height1 = photo1.height()
canvas1 = Canvas(width=width1, height=height1)
canvas1.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH) # <--- Make your canvas expandable.
x = (width1)/2.0
y = (height1)/2.0
item = canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo1) # <--- Save the return value of the create_* method.
canvas1.bind('<Button-1>', next_image)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by moving infinite times...
Do you want to the image to come back to left once it touches the right side boundary and start over again??

Comment: Are you aware you can move the object to any location you want with the `coords` method? Are you aware you can use negative values in the `move` method?

Comment: @BryanOakley: how I am I supposed to do code this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to check for whether the object has moved off the right edge, and move it back to the left:

```
def next_image(event=None):

    maxwidth = canvas1.winfo_width()
    x0,y0 = canvas1.coords(item)
    if x0 > maxwidth:
        canvas1.coords(item, (0,y0))
    else:
        canvas1.move(item, 10, 0)

    canvas1.after(20, next_image)# <--- Use Canvas.move method.
```